# matplotlib mySQL blank plot

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib

I made this Python script. The idea is using this Python script so that matplotlib can generate a vertical bar chart for me using data from a MySQL database. Another thing I want to do is saving the png file instead of displaying it (I am trying to run this code via putty), which I think I did it correctly. When I run the code, I got some error which I have no idea what it means. Hopefully someone can point out where I did wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# matplotlib pyplot module
import MySQLdb
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# connect to MySQL database
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="xx", passwd="xxxx", db="r1array")

# prepare a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

# this is the query we will be making
query = """
SELECT TimeStamp,Pac 
FROM SolarData 
WHERE TimeStamp >= "2014-01-03" 
  AND TimeStamp < "2014-01-04";
"""

# execute the query
cur.execute(query)

# retrieve the whole result set
data = cur.fetchall()

# close cursor and connection
cur.close()
conn.close()

# unpack data in TimeStamp (x axis) and Pac (y axis)
TimeStamp, Pac = zip(*data)

# graph code
plt.bar(TimeStamp, Pac, align='center')

# set title, X/Y labels
plt.title("PVIC R1 panel")
plt.xlabel("Time of Day")
plt.ylabel("Pac")
fig = plt.gcf()

# plt.xticks(TimeStamp, (hour))
fig.set_size_inches(20.5,10.5)
plt.grid(True)
plt.draw()
fig.savefig('test2.png', dpi=100)
```

The error message I got is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python_sql_image.py", line 41, in <module>
        plt.savefig('test.png')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 356, in savefig
        return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1032, in savefig
        self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1476, in print_figure
        **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 358, in print_png
        FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 314, in draw
        self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 46, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *kl)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 773, in draw
        for a in self.axes: a.draw(renderer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 46, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *kl)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1735, in draw
        a.draw(renderer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 46, in draw_wrapper
        draw(artist, renderer, *kl)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 736, in draw
        for tick, loc, label in self.iter_ticks():
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 680, in iter_ticks
        majorLabels = [self.major.formatter(val, i) for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 417, in __call__
        return self._formatter(x, pos)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 293, in __call__
        dt = num2date(x, self.tz)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 249, in num2date
        if not cbook.iterable(x): return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 170, in _from_ordinalf
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix)
    ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

especially the last line, I don't get this.

```
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

This is the data I called from MySQL database.

```
 TimeStamp           | Pac  |
+---------------------+------+
| 2014-01-03 07:55:02 |    0 |
| 2014-01-03 08:00:02 |    0 |
| 2014-01-03 08:05:02 |    2 |
| 2014-01-03 08:10:02 |   11 |
| 2014-01-03 08:15:03 |   72 |
| 2014-01-03 08:20:04 |  162 |
| 2014-01-03 08:25:04 |  307 |
| 2014-01-03 08:30:04 |  464 |
| 2014-01-03 08:40:01 |  665 |
| 2014-01-03 08:45:01 |  764 |
| 2014-01-03 08:50:02 |  844 |
| 2014-01-03 08:55:01 |  931 |
| 2014-01-03 09:00:02 | 1017 |
| 2014-01-03 09:05:02 | 1098 |
| 2014-01-03 09:10:01 | 1176 |
| 2014-01-03 09:15:02 | 1272 |
| 2014-01-03 09:20:01 | 1351 |
| 2014-01-03 09:25:02 | 1432 |
| 2014-01-03 09:30:01 | 1528 |
| 2014-01-03 09:35:02 | 1653 |
| 2014-01-03 09:40:02 | 1738 |
| 2014-01-03 09:45:01 | 1821 |
| 2014-01-03 09:50:02 | 1895 |
| 2014-01-03 09:55:01 | 2015 |
| 2014-01-03 10:00:02 | 2153 |
| 2014-01-03 10:05:01 | 2300 |
| 2014-01-03 10:10:02 | 2482 |
| 2014-01-03 10:15:02 | 2635 |
| 2014-01-03 10:20:01 | 2750 |
| 2014-01-03 10:25:02 | 2923 |
| 2014-01-03 10:30:01 | 3059 |
| 2014-01-03 10:35:02 | 3201 |
| 2014-01-03 10:40:01 | 3275 |
| 2014-01-03 10:45:02 | 3360 |
```

What I need is a bar chart. Right now I am able to get an image but it's just a wrong image. 
[image: bad bar plot]

Comment: MySQL isn't the issue here. Show us the data you're trying to plot (in a copy/pastable form) and then we can start tracking down the issue. In general, the ValueError you're seeing means matplotlib can't parse one or more of the dates you passed to it.

Comment: as a first measure change `plt.xlim(0, 23)` and `plt.xticks(range(0, 23, 2))` to  `plt.xlim(2, 23)` and `plt.xticks(range(2, 23, 2))`. my guess is that you probably want to remove those lines altogether since you're plotting dates from this year, not year 1 (or the unix epoch, or whatever).

Comment: @PaulH, I posted the MySQL table. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: close enough -- did you try the suggestions in my other comment?

Comment: @PaulH. I did, and no bugs!! I've got the png file under the same folder. But I got a blank plot though, which I am trying to fix.

Comment: @PaulH, please take a look at the blank image link I added at the end of the post. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to include the minimum amount of code necessary to generate that image. Leave off the MySQL stuff b/c that's not the issue here. In other words, if after fetching the data from MySQL, you end up with a list of tuples (or some other structure), just include 10 to 20 of the rows in a copy/pastable format so that we can execute *your* code the same way as you.

Comment: @PaulH, I changed the code a bit and I am able to get an image, but the image looks weird. You can see the new image still via the same link I posted.

Comment: See my edits and please take note of how my example code is self-contained. Including code in such a manner greatly facilitates tracking down the problem.

Comment: @PaulH, I did go through your new post. But I cannot compile the code on my machine. The problem comes from this line `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))`. It says `AttributeError: unknown property figsize`.
I think the correct syntax is `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= x,y,(8,4))`. But I don't know what value should I give to x and y.

Comment: for this line again, `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= x,y,(8,4))`, I think x and y should be 1 and 1 since they represent nrows and ncols (of diagram) in this plot. I only have one diagram. But I still cannot understand why I have problem on figsize..

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have? Be sure to type it out exactly as it appears in my answer. if you want to be more verbose, you can do `fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(8,4))`. The syntax you have above is absolutely incorrect. See my edited (yet again), response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a recent version of pandas, you should use the `read_sql` function...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import MySQLdb

# connect to MySQL database 
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="xx", passwd="xxxx", db="r1array")


# this is the query we will be making 
query = """ 
SELECT TimeStamp, Pac  
FROM SolarData  
WHERE TimeStamp >= "2014-01-03"
  AND TimeStamp < "2014-01-04"; 
"""

df = pandas.read_sql(query, conn, index_col=['TimeStamp'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax)
conn.close()
```

Setting your `TimeStamp` column as the index of the dataframe will let pandas know that it goes on the x-axis.

I converted a small subset of data you posted to a CSV, and all other things equal, I get this:
[image: time series plot]

### response to comments:

Since you really want a bar plot, here's a solution to the problem you're having. The default width for bar plots in matplotlib is 0.8. You can find this by looking at the docstring for `pyplot.bar`. Point is, 0.8 of what? Well when you have a time axis, that's 0.8 days, or a little over 19 hours. So just set that `width` kwarg to something more sensible.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


Pac = [
    0,0,2,11,72,162,307,464,665,764,844,931,1017,1098,1176,1272,1351,1432,
    1528,1653,1738,1821,1895,2015,2153,2300,2482,2635,2750,2923,3059,3201,
    3275,3360
]
TimeStamp = mdates.num2date(mdates.datestr2num([
    '2014-01-03 07:55:02', '2014-01-03 08:00:02', '2014-01-03 08:05:02', '2014-01-03 08:10:02', 
    '2014-01-03 08:15:03', '2014-01-03 08:20:04', '2014-01-03 08:25:04', '2014-01-03 08:30:04', 
    '2014-01-03 08:40:01', '2014-01-03 08:45:01', '2014-01-03 08:50:02', '2014-01-03 08:55:01', 
    '2014-01-03 09:00:02', '2014-01-03 09:05:02', '2014-01-03 09:10:01', '2014-01-03 09:15:02', 
    '2014-01-03 09:20:01', '2014-01-03 09:25:02', '2014-01-03 09:30:01', '2014-01-03 09:35:02', 
    '2014-01-03 09:40:02', '2014-01-03 09:45:01', '2014-01-03 09:50:02', '2014-01-03 09:55:01', 
    '2014-01-03 10:00:02', '2014-01-03 10:05:01', '2014-01-03 10:10:02', '2014-01-03 10:15:02', 
    '2014-01-03 10:20:01', '2014-01-03 10:25:02', '2014-01-03 10:30:01', '2014-01-03 10:35:02', 
    '2014-01-03 10:40:01', '2014-01-03 10:45:02'
]))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.bar(TimeStamp, Pac, align='center', width=0.002)
```

And that gives me:

[image]

Comment: I need to make a vertical bar chart...I didn't use pandas, but I will look into it.

Comment: @ShuruiLiu does the new version help?

Comment: Instead of updating to a newer version, I just edited your answer a bit on this line `ax.bar(TimeStamp, Pac, align='center', width=0.002)`. It works when I changed it like this `plt.bar(TimeStamp, Pac, align='center', width=0.002)`.

Comment: Do you know how to use xlim to set the range for x axis? I tried to do that but I keep getting errors. I think the hardest thing here is giving a range with the format of TimeStamp from MySQL.

Comment: @ShuruiLiu you should open a separate question for that. if this answer solves the current question (how to do barplots with timestamp data), you should accept it.